# R - how to concat a vector into a string?

Tags: r, vector

I have this data for instance,

```
>rows
  ID  NAME AGE    ADDRESS SALARY
1  1  Paul  32 California  20000
2  2 Allen  25      Texas  15000
3  3 Teddy  23     Norway  20000
4  4  Mark  25 Rich-Mond   65000
5  5 David  27      Texas  85000
6  6   Kim  22 South-Hall  45000
```

and to get the data in the name columns only,

```
> rows[2]
   NAME
1  Paul
2 Allen
3 Teddy
4  Mark
5 David
6   Kim
```

And I want to join them into a string,

```
> paste(rows[2],collapse=" ")
```

result,

```
[1] c("Paul", "Allen", "Teddy", "Mark", "David", "Kim")
```

But this is what I am after,

```
Paul Allen Teddy Mark David Kim
```

Is it possible?

The entire code,

```
# Load package.
library("RSQLite")

# Load package.
library("sqldf")

# Load package.
library("tcltk")

# Connect to the sqlite file.
# Localhost.
DB <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "C:/../sqldf/testDB.sqlite3")

# Fetch all records in the table.
users <- dbGetQuery(
    DB,
    "SELECT *
    FROM users"
)

# SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext
rows <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM users")

png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)

plot(1, 1, col = "white")
text(1, 1, paste(rows[2], collapse = ' '))

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use either

```
paste(rows[,2], collapse=' ')
```

Or

```
paste(rows[[2]], collapse=' ')
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can extract by the name of the column using either `$`

```
paste(rows$NAME, collapse=' ')
```

Or `[[`

```
paste(rows[['NAME']], collapse=' ')
```

as all of the above are extracting the columns as `vector` while `rows[2]` is still a data.frame.  We can check the difference using `str` i.e. `str(rows[2])` and `str(rows[[2]])`.  For more info, we can look at `?Extract` or `?'['`

Comment: Or `"NAME"` in the place of `2` in the first two as well.

Comment: thanks! what is wrong with `paste(rows[2], collapse=' ')` btw?